# Method invocation in "Implement Interface Explicitly" classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I would like to understand what **Implement Interface Explicitly** entails in C# based on the contexts/scenarios described below. Lets say I have the following **interface**:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    void Operation1();
    void Operation2();
}
```

Lets say I implement the interface explicitly as shown below, is it possible, using whatever means to call Operation2() from Operation1()?

```
public sealed class TestService : ITestService
{
    public TestService(){}

    void ITestService.Operation1()
    {
        // HOW WOULD ONE SUCCESSFULLY INVOKE Operation2() FROM HERE. Like:
        Operation2();
    }

    void ITestService.Operation2()
    {

    }
}
```

What happens differently (under the wraps) to allow testService1 and testService2 declared differently below behave differently?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITestService testService1 = new TestService();      
        testService1.Operation1(); // => Works: WHY IS THIS POSSIBLE, ESPECIALLY SINCE Operation1() AND Operation2() WOULD BE *DEEMED* private?
        // *DEEMED* since access modifiers on functions are not permitted in an interface

        // while ...
        TestService testService2 = new TestService();
        testService2.Operation1(); //! Fails: As expected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void ITestService.Operation1()
{
    ((ITestService)this).Operation2();
}
```

As for your second question:

All members of interfaces are public. Hence the implementation will be public too.

Comment: Well, makes me feel dumb :) I never imagined that all I needed to do was to cast to **this** to **ITestService**. Thanks all the same sir.

Answer (score 1):

for your 2nd question

> testService1.Operation1(); // => Works: WHY IS THIS POSSIBLE,
>   ESPECIALLY SINCE Operation1() AND Operation2() WOULD BE *DEEMED*
>   private?

Because the functions in interface are public you can call them. Also, you have explicitly implemented the interface methods, you can't call it against the class object. e.g.

```
TestService ts = new TestService();
ts.Operation1();// this would cause an error
```

You may see: [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157)